# Execute python method from a string

Tags: python-3.x, methods, getattr

I have a string that has the method name and value in it. Currently, I'm using the following implementation which works but doesn't seem elegant. Is there a better way to implement this?

```
class ObjectResolver:

    def methodResolver(self, value):
        """Some logic here"""
        print(value)


objectResolver = ObjectResolver()

channel = 'methodResolver(helloWorld)'

findValue = channel.strip().find('(')
objectMethod = channel.strip()[:findValue]
attribute = channel.strip()[findValue:][1:-1]

channelResolver = getattr(objectResolver, objectMethod)(attribute)
```

Output:

```
helloWorld
```

Comment: There are [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) and [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).

Comment: @Asocia I have tried exec, It needs my whole class to be inside a string, from what I understood. But the issue is I'm using the class at other places also. I will checkout eval also.

Comment: @Asocia So, I checked out eval also, the issue I found is I have to use `value = helloWorld` and then use `eval(methodResolver(value))` which will give the required output. In such a case, I still have to extract `helloWorld` out and set it to a variable.

Comment: @AnshumanGhosh can you upload a detailed code for class-based usage in exec? Also, I hope you now exec() is very anti-pattern and can expose serious security issues in your application.

Comment: @Sarmad updated the code with better formating to avoid confusion and implemented the eval functionality.

Comment: @Sarmad and @Asocia thank you for the help, I didn't know about `eval`. I have posted the exact answer based on my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method I found is to use eval here and specifically to my question above, the implementation is as follows:

```
class ObjectResolver:

    def methodResolver(self, value):
        """Some logic here"""
        print(value)


objectResolver = ObjectResolver()

channel = "methodResolver('helloWorld')"
handlers = dict(methodResolver=objectResolver.methodResolver)
eval(channel, handlers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` or `exec()`

```
class ObjectResolver:

def methodResolver(self, value):
    """Some logic here"""
    print(value)


objectResolver = ObjectResolver()

// Something like this...
channel = eval('methodResolver')(helloWorld)
// OR
exec('channel = "methodResolver(helloWorld)"')

findValue = channel.strip().find('(')
objectMethod = channel.strip()[:findValue]
attribute = channel.strip()[findValue:][1:-1]
channelResolver = getattr(objectResolver, objectMethod)(attribute)
```

Learn more about [`eval`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) and [`exec`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec)